# Excel or Access change some rows to columns

Tags: python, excel

I have some long data I need to convert into a wide fixed width text format.

I have a large spreadsheet of rows that are duplicated for each person where the only difference, where the person is the same, are two columns.

I want to remove the duplicates and instead of having multiple rows where the only difference are the columns 'type' and 'process'.  They are all in the same row and repeated 30 times each, some columns would be blank if there are not 30 rows for that person.  I've attached a picture if my explanation makes no sense: [image]

I'm not sure if this can be done in VBA, or python or other language would be better

Comment: Looks like a pivot table to me... Have you tested that?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using a pivot table:

- put name then DOB as row labels
- put type then process as column labels
- put count of process in values
- right-click your pivot table, select expand/collapse and expand by process
- go to design, report layout, and select tabular layout
- right click on totals rows and columns that you do not want and hide them

Here's how it looks for me, for a smaller table:

[image]

Comment: hi, I tried a pivot table first (I should have mentioned), but I do not want an extra column for each, plus there is a limit to columns if I do it this way.

Comment: not sure i understand you, i thought type and process were repeated 30 times each?

Comment: yes they are repeated 30 times, but not every code and item has it's own column.  There will be a range of 1000s of either, but most will not have more than 10 codes or items.